# Scrapy : Select only <p> elements with text content with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'd like to select only `<p></p>` with some text inside. What is the best possible to do that with xpath?

Html sample :

```
    <div id="date" >
            <span > Some date</span>
            <p></p>
    </div>
        <div id="date" >
            <span >Some date</span>
            <p>10:00</p>
    </div>
```

Xpath

```
item['StartTime'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="date"]/p/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
date = response.xpath('//div[@id="date"]')
for d in date:
    ptext = d.xpath('p/text()').extract()
    if ptext:
       item['StartTime'] = ptext
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul, but this select `<p></p>` too, i.e without text.

Comment: Then use an `if` statement to filter out the empty tags.

Comment: Even better, use a predicate `p[normalize-space()]` to filter out empty (i.e. whitespace-only) `p` tags.

Comment: It helped me to find a solution to my problem.  My initial question wasn't specific enough. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

How about using this XPath :

```
//*[@id="date"]/p[normalize-space()]/text()
```

The expression `p[normalize-space()]` will return `p` elements that contains non-empty text.